# How to hide an element before it reaches the top of the screen? window.onscroll = function()

Tags: javascript, menu, onscroll, scroll-position

```js
< script >
  document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "-10vh";
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos < currentScrollPos) {
      document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "-10vh";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "0";
    }
    if (currentScrollPos == 0) {
      document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "-10vh";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
  }

  <
  /script>
```

```css
<style>body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Karla';
  font-size: 22px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container1 {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.header {
  margin-left: 190px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 100;
}

.backgroundimage {
  background-image: url("M0000-021-014_edited.jpg");
  /* Full height */
  height: 100vh;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.7;
  position: relative;
}

.leftthing {
  width: calc(100% - 400px);
  float: left;
}

.leftthing img {
  width: 100%;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.show {
  display: none;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: white;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Karla';
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*        menu*/

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 10vh;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
  padding: 16px 16px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

li a:hover,
li a:focus {
  color: black;
  opacity: 1;
}


/*        menu moving footer*/

#bottommenu {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  /*            margin-left: 60px;*/
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  /*            padding: 0px;*/
  /*            text-align: left;*/
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: bottom 0.5s;
  height: 10vh;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="backgroundimage"></div>
  <div class="container1">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="logo" onclick="scrollWin()">|bacheva
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="leftthing">
    <img src="82213112_611171039713397_1145784978357878784_n.jpg" alt="building concept">
    <img src="INTERIOR%20RENDER.jpg" alt="interior render">
    <img src="exterior%20render.jpg" alt="exterior render">
    <img src="big%20ground%20floor%20plan.jpg" alt="floor plan">
    <img src="READY%20CLIMATE%20SCHEME.jpg" alt="climate scheme">
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>


  <div class="container">
    <ul style="font-family: 'Karla';font-size:22px;">
      <li><a href="about_final.html">|about</a></li>
      <li><a href="project%20page_final.html">|work</a></li>
      <li><a href="home_final.html">|home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="bottommenu">
    <ul style="font-size:22px;">
      <li><a href="about_final.html">|about</a></li>
      <li><a href="project%20page_final.html">|work</a></li>
      <li><a href="home_final.html">|home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have the following page:

- I full-screen background picture
- some content with pictures when you scroll down
- and a menu on the bottom right (with a height of 10vh)

I am using a javascript function that does the following: When you scroll down the menu is not shown, but when you scroll up the content, the menu appears on the bottom right. When you reach the full-screen background picture on the top the menu is set to hide again to not obstruct the picture. However, currently when you reach the top of the page, you see the menu for a millisecond before it hides again. Therefore, my question is: Can I alternate the javascript function and tell the menu to disappear 10vh before it reaches the full-size background picture so I would not see it before it disappears when I reach the top of the page.

Here is the function I am using:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "-10vh";
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
        var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
        if (prevScrollpos < currentScrollPos) {
            document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "-10vh";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "0";
        }
        if (currentScrollPos == 0) {
            document.getElementById("bottommenu").style.bottom = "-10vh";
        }
        prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
</script>
```

Looking at the last 'if' the menu disappears when the current scroll is '0', but I would rather have it disappear before it reaches this last possible scroll (before it reaches the full-screen background picture.)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan do you mean that my description is too short, too long or not clear enough? Sorry, I'm new to this platform.

Comment: `Minimal reproducible` simply means the minimal amount of code that shows your problem. Your question currently does not include that (in your case, it's missing the html and optionally css if its needed to reproduce the problem). Check and carefully read the link in the above comment.

Comment: I tried to edit the question as you suggested.